# django building a site with different apps

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to build a site with a dynamic menu which should be delivered from an separate app named menu. This app uses a base template.
On the other side there is a content which cames from another app named customer.
When i call domain/customer/show/1 for example the site should show the selected customer and also the menu from the menuapp but the customerapp shall be independent.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to try [django-sitetree](https://github.com/idlesign/django-sitetree) or other app from this list http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/navigation/